# How can I know which directory corresponds to which firefox extension?

Tags: linux, firefox, firefox-extensions

In my firefox's `extensions` folder (`~/.mozilla/firefox/PROFILECODE.default/extensions`, I have a list of folders and `.xpi` files most of which have unintelligible names:

```
 {0538E3E3-7E9B-4d49-8831-A227C80A7AD3}      chromifox@altmusictv.com
{1280606b-2510-4fe0-97ef-9b5a22eafe30}.xpi  clearfields@alex.alexander.googlepages.com.xpi
{1f369631-31dd-43a8-8597-e159af817152}.xpi  cybersearch@cybernetnews.com
{1f870b8e-d71f-11db-8314-0800200c9a66}      {d10d0bf8-f5b5-c8b4-a8b2-2b9879e08c5d}.xpi
{3e559c3c-4aad-4168-bd47-e1056298df8e}      {D4DD63FA-01E4-46a7-B6B1-EDAB7D6AD389}.xpi
{41a40cb1-aa9e-47c6-a207-66b9f5875870}.xpi  {dc572301-7619-498c-a57d-39143191b318}.xpi
{44d0a1b4-9c90-4f86-ac92-8680b5d6549e}      {e0204bd5-9d31-402b-a99d-a6aa8ffebdca}
{6DF67709-ECE1-4252-BC58-BA8E2320DA7E}.xpi  {e4a8a97b-f2ed-450b-b12d-ee082ba24781}.xpi
7.blaze.7@live.com                          es-es@dictionaries.addons.mozilla.org
{81514210-E22A-4e69-93D5-E1EFD45B4620}      filtersetg@updater
{8b86149f-01fb-4842-9dd8-4d7eb02fd055}      fr-dicollecte@dictionaries.addons.mozilla.org
{a7c6cf7f-112c-4500-a7ea-39801a327e5f}      max@subfighter.com
artur.dubovoy@gmail.com                     rein@notiz.jp
{b7a583a0-519b-11db-b0de-0800200c9a66}      silvermel@pardal.de.xpi
{b9db16a4-6edc-47ec-a1f4-b86292ed211d}      silvermelxt@pardal.de.xpi
{c0c9a2c7-2e5c-4447-bc53-97718bc91e1b}.xpi  stackexchange-notifications@jetpack.xpi
cfxec@Triton                                tabx@clav.mozdev.org
cfxHelper@Triton                            tineye@ideeinc.com
```

While some of these are named in a way that is informative (`clearfields@alex.alexander.googlepages.com.xpi` for example), others simply have a hex string as a name. Is there a way for me to map these to the corresponding extension's human-readable name?

I'm using firefox 30 on a 64bit Debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on `Help | Troubleshooting Information` (if you don't see the menus, you can show them by clicking on the 3-bar symbol on the right, click Customize in the lower left of the window, and the Show/Hide toolbars option will be in the lower left of the Firefox window).

This will open a window with a lot of information on things like internal settings.  Near the top is a section called Extensions.  The ID field on the right has that information.